# How to configure routes in Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have requirement like [image]

header, sidemenu, innerpages(profile,about..)

I want 3 seperate routes(1-header,2-sidemenu,3-innerpages)
when application is loading profile page is come first

I tried like

**app.rouutes.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', redirectTo: '/business', pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**business.routes.ts**

```
const BUSINESS_ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: 'header',  component: BusinessHeaderComponent },
  { path: 'sidemenu',  component: BusinessSidemeuComponent },

  { path: 'about',  component: BusinessComponent }

  ];

@NgModule({
 imports: [
  RouterModule.forChild(BUSINESS_ROUTES)
],
exports: [
  RouterModule
]
 })
export class BusinessRoutingModule { }
```

Please help  me to configure it

Comment: What have you tried so far? I would also suggest reading the angular 2 documentation around this and then try to implement and ask a question if you get stuck.  https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Comment: Please put your code with what have you tried.

Comment: I see no reason why you would have a route for the header and a route for your side menu. You're confusing routes with sections of the page.

Comment: No I want seperate routes, because in my project we have two module, user, admin, for that differnt sidemenu, header will be there, but common inner pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're mixing the concept of routes with layouts, routes are reflection of urls, if you enter /business/header you will get BusinessHeaderComponent alone, that's routing... what you need is child routes, when you enter business/about, it should load the business header, sidemenu and about component

```
{
  path: '', redirectTo: '/business', pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
    path: 'business',
    component: BusinessLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'about',
        component: AboutComponent,
      },
    ]
  },
 {
    path: 'user',
    component: UserLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'about',
        component: AboutComponent,
      },
    ]
  },
```

Now inside BusinessLayoutComponent and UserLayoutComponent templates, add your header and side bar as pure html, no need for components for that, because that's the only place they would be defined

The layout components are very simple HTML pages with headers and sidebars and a single  `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` tag to contain the child components.

The child components could be anything, like an about page with About content.

Of course you can use the same about component in both routes

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'common/about.html'
})
export class AboutComponent {
    constructor() { }
}
```

Comment: can it possible to write  component: CoreComponents.BusinessComponent, Plese provide some examples

Comment: Removed CoreComponents, sorry that's the way I do it, but it isn't required

Comment: Ok. One thing I did not understood, You said **BusinessLayoutComponent and UserLayoutComponent templates, add your header and side bar as pure html, no need for components for that** If like in every module I should write header, sidemenu

Comment: Yes i mean you do not need components for headers and sidebars, but the Layout is a component of course

Comment: it's not possible to header,sidemenu as unique for all modules like businee, user,staff

Comment: the idea of a Layout is a master page for all pages that share the same menus and headers, all links that have the same layout should either be below /business, or use the same LayoutComponent in the entry first route

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132889/discussion-between-soumya-gangamwar-and-ayyash).

Comment: if that answers your question maybe you want to mark this as the answer?